# Bootstrap modal - return focus upon close & tabindex="-1"

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, accessibility, tabindex

I am using bootstrap modal to open a window but when the window is closed the focus is NOT returned to the link that opened it but rather the container, which has tabindex="-1". Code snippets as follows:

```
<a href="#" id="exitLink" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#endsession_confirm">Exit</a>

<div class="modal fade in" id="endsession_confirm" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="endsession_confirm" aria-hidden="false">
```

I think this is because I am using tabindex="-1" on my main content area for skip links:

```
<div id=”main” tabindex=”-1”>
  <p>Main content goes here</p>
  <a href=”#”>a link in the main body</a>
</div>
```

Any help on how to overcome this problem?

Comment: You can try JavaScript for this.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
$(document).on( "click", "[data-toggle='modal']", function() {
   var trigger = $(this)
   var modal = $( trigger.data("target") )

   // When bootstrap's modal "hidden" event fires, return focus to the trigger
   // Notice the binding is using $.fn.one as opposed to using $.fn.on
   modal.one("hidden.bs.modal", function() { trigger.focus() })
})
```

This will listen to any element with an attribute "data-toggle='modal'
and return focus once the modal it controls closes.

This can be refined to a specific trigger by changing the [delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) selector to:

```
$( "#myachor" ).on( "click", function() {..})
```

[Bootstrap modal events docs](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals-events)

Comment: Thanks. I'm just wondering WHY this is an issue though as the bootstrap framework doesn't have this problem?

Comment: It seems that if the trigger is an anchor tag, the focus is not returned to to the trigger ( it does however work when using the button tag)

Comment: I'm getting the following error: 

Error: TypeError: trigger.data is not a function

Comment: What version of jquery are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/88581/discussion-between-j00m-and-elad-chen).

Comment: jQuery v1.11.1 - stuck with that version Im afraid